# Why websense not allowing homepage url(youtube) but a video page?

Tags: web-browser

My company uses Websense, when someone goes to youtube by directly hitting url from browser 
it says it's blocked due to category :Entertainment.

When someone searches for a video in google and clicks it , they can see the video , how is this possible?

If someone could say how its possible, i could make a work-around application if possible

Answer (score 3):

Websense can be setup with either/or automatic and manual categorizations. In this case, I suspect that YouTube has been manually added as an "entertainment" site by your company. Video sites other than YouTube may not have been categorized.

As for creating a workaround, that's your perogative, though browsing patterns may be highlighted causing your Websense admins to apply additional filters.

Comment: I've found some are blocked through search phrases/words like proxy,hack etc.,
As i said Youtube is blocked saying
      This Websense category is filtered: Streaming Media.
But i don't understand why web-sense behaves diff during sometimes(not that my admins have web-sense maintenance all those times), becoz right now i'm able to browse all sites without any blockage in safari browser, but my friend in same organization with everything same couldn't access.
Does web-sense filter traffic through the client basis also?
if so, how can i make web requests without popular clients.

Comment: My experience with Websense is somewhat limited. I don't know if if can or would be filtered by the user agent, but certainly can be filtered by the end user, source network/IP address, group, or by things like the time of day. No one can divine the true reason, but we can give general guidance.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the specifics of your organisation's deployment:

- Excessive load can result in intermittent/inconsistent filtering.
- Subscripton status and frequency: if YouTube load balance to, or add,
  a new public IP to their service this may be not known by your Websense deployment until the address is either manually added or updated via subscription.
- Whether traffic is proxied (explicitly or    transparently) via the
  Websense proxy interface(s) or monitored via    the Network Agent
  (span) will determine how it is detected and    filtered. SPAN
  traffic is L3 IP not domain name-based.
- Your comment around different browsers impacting filtering may indicate an explicit proxy configured in your corporate browser, via PAC or otherwise.